# Where do I find the history for the gnome shell command prompt?

Tags: gnome

Where do I find the history for the gnome shell command prompt? I mean the one that is normally started with Alt+F2. I'm running GNOME Shell v3.10.4.

Or alternatively: how can I delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will do:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell command-history
```